# How to get a value of same column which is being search with where clause

Tags: sql-server

```
------------------------------------------------
| UserId |       Checktime          | Checktype
|   1    | 12/05/2015 09:00:00:0000 | I
|   1    | 12/05/2015 18:00:00:0000 | O
|   1    | 12/04/2015 09:00:00:0000 | I
|   1    | 12/04/2015 18:00:00:0000 | O
|   2    | 12/05/2015 09:00:00:0000 | I
|   2    | 12/05/2015 18:00:00:0000 | O
|   2    | 12/04/2015 09:00:00:0000 | I
|   2    | 12/04/2015 18:00:00:0000 | O
```

I want to retrieve only time from `Checktime` of `UserId` = `1` and `date` = `12/05/2015` and `Checktype` = `I` in my result set.

Comment: Please re-write/re-format your question so it can be read by human beings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You select query to retrieve data and filter data where date is greater than 12/04/2015 and less than 13/04/2015 and userId =1.

So your query will be something like this.

Mysl Query:-

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(Checktime,'%H:%i:%s') as TIME from TABLE_NAME where UserId=1 and Checktype='I' and Checktime>='12/04/2015' and Checktime <'13/04/2015'
```

EDIT:- 
SQL Server 2008

```
SELECT CONVERT(TIME,Checktime) AS TIME from TABLE_NAME where UserId=1 and Checktype='I' and Checktime>='12/04/2015' and Checktime <'13/04/2015'
```

Comment: undefine function of date_format
I m using sql server

Comment: @user3670451 Updated the answer...I answered earlier for mysql